# How to check the second element of an array in linq only if it exists

Tags: c#, linq

If i have a list of People which are instances of a Person class and each Person has an array which stores phone numbers linked to their account. Some people only have a home phone number, some people have a mobile number too so the size of this array isn't fixed, it can have either one or two elements. How would i do a linq search to find accounts with a specific phone number? So far i have:

```
List<int> NumbersOfConcern; // A list of the phone numbers i am searching

List<Person> validPeople = PersonList.FindAll(p => 
        (NumbersOfConcern.Contains(p.PhoneNumbers[0].ToString()) || // Check accounts primary number
        NumbersOfConcern.Contains(p.PhoneNumbers[1].ToString()))); // Check accounts secondary number
```

This code causes a crash for all accounts that dont have a secondary number registered as its trying to access non-existent data and i dont know linq well enough to know how to do this search, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` + `Any`

```
List<Person> validPeople = PersonList
    .FindAll(p => NumbersOfConcern.Intersect(p.PhoneNumbers).Any());
```

For best performance the bigger list should be the first, so `NumbersOfConcern` here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0) in your Linq code.

```
List<int> NumbersOfConcern; // A list of the phone numbers i am searching

List<Person> validPeople = PersonList.FindAll(p => 
        (NumbersOfConcern.Contains(p.PhoneNumbers[0].ToString()) || // Check accounts primary number
        NumbersOfConcern.Contains(p.PhoneNumbers[1]?.ToString()))); // Check accounts secondary number
```

Do you need to call `ToString` on the PhoneNumbers array items, as NumberOfConcern is of type `List<int>`?

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem is more: "does an item in one enumerable, exist in another". Aside from `Intersect`, this is how I would flatten the phone number array and check if they exist in the numbers of concern.

```
var validPeople = people
                .Where(person => numbersOfConcern.Any(number => person.PhoneNumbers.Select(phoneNumber => phoneNumber.Number).Contains(number)))
                .ToList();
```

And a fully working example- Here Jim and Jane Smith have the same home phone number, but differing work numbers. And Jon, not being a Smith, has a different home number. If the number of concern is the Smiths home number it would look something like this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new Person[]
            {
                new Person()
                {
                    FullName = "Jim Smith",
                    PhoneNumbers = new PhoneNumber[]
                    {
                        new PhoneNumber() { Number = "111-222-3333", Type = PhoneNumberType.Home },
                        new PhoneNumber() { Number = "111-222-4444", Type = PhoneNumberType.Work }
                    }
                },
                new Person()
                {
                    FullName = "Jane Smith",
                    PhoneNumbers = new PhoneNumber[]
                    {
                        new PhoneNumber() { Number = "111-222-3333", Type = PhoneNumberType.Home },
                        new PhoneNumber() { Number = "111-222-5555", Type = PhoneNumberType.Work }
                    }
                },
                new Person()
                {
                    FullName = "Jon Roberts",
                    PhoneNumbers = new PhoneNumber[]
                    {
                        new PhoneNumber() { Number = "222-555-1234", Type = PhoneNumberType.Home }
                    }
                }
            };

            var numbersOfConcern = new string[] { "111-222-3333" };

            var validPeople = people
                .Where(person => numbersOfConcern.Any(number => person.PhoneNumbers.Select(phoneNumber => phoneNumber.Number).Contains(number)))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var validPerson in validPeople)
            {
                var flattenedPhoneNumbers = validPerson.PhoneNumbers.Select(phoneNumber => $"{phoneNumber.Type}:{phoneNumber.Number}").ToArray();
                Console.WriteLine($"{validPerson.FullName} : {string.Join(", ", flattenedPhoneNumbers)}");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public PhoneNumber[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhoneNumber
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public PhoneNumberType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum PhoneNumberType
    {
        Home,
        Work,
        Cell
    }
```